# WebSockets not working with HTTP/2 Load Balancer backend in GCP

Tags: networking, websocket, google-cloud-platform, http2, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have an application running behind a Load Balancer in Google Cloud Platform.

When I use the HTTPS protocol in the backend, I'm able to connect with WebSockets and all WebSocket connections work fine. However, when I change the backend protocol to HTTP/2, I'm unable to connect from the application, and it returns a response of `502 Bad Gateway`.

Can I use WebSockets with HTTP/2, or do I need to perform some configuration in order to use WebSockets with an HTTP2 backend?

Comment: Websocket proxy should be transparent for the load balancer, in the documentation it doesn't say much about the HTTP2 protocol. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support

Comment: hello @Pievis but i am unable to understand Websocket proxy should be transparent for the load balancer can  please explain me this line? thank you

Comment: The WebSocket handshake requires HTTP/1.1 (for now)... If you're forcing all communication into HTTP/2, you will break the WebSocket handshake. This is because HTTP/2 does **not** support the `Upgrade` directive.

Comment: Additional information: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#websocket_proxy_support

Comment: Do not use HTTP/2 backends with WebSockets. The load balancer will forward HTTP Upgrade Protocol request to the backends, which will fail.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, WebSockets are not supported in HTTP/2 and this is the reason why you receive the 5XX error.

Having said that, the WebSocket functionality is achievable (and improved) with HTTP/2 [ref](https://www.infoq.com/articles/websocket-and-http2-coexist/).

If you have existing code working with WebSocket it might not be great to rewrite both backend and frontend.

However, if you are developing a new asynchronous service, it is a good idea to take a look at the HTTP/2 + Server Sent Event (SSE) scheme.